# When will Travis-ci will support NixOS/NixOps?

Tags: travis-ci, nixos, nix, nixops

Currently travis supports [linux (ubuntu?) and mac](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/).

I'm currently exploring nix. I think it's a powerful way to declare the global state of your system. It's available at various level:

- [nix: package](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/)
- [nixos: machine](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/)
- [nixops: deployment](http://nixos.org/nixops/manual/)

With the current state, I could install nix the package manager on a linux vm and get all the packages I need, great!

In my ideal world, I could do the same at the machine or at the deployment level (machine[s]).

So my question is: When will travis-ci will support NixOS? When will travis-ci will support multiple machine setup (let's say with NixOps) ?

Answer (score 2):

it would be nice to be able to share `/nix/store` between travis builds. but for nixpkgs we're already try to build changes using `nox` tool.

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/.travis.yml